# Get all from emails in Gmail via Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am playing around with google's extensions and I want to access all the 'from' emails on my Gmail page.

I located where the values is stored but there doesn't look to be any logical class structure I can follow:

[image: Gmail structure]

I want to be able to loop through each one something like this:

```
var map = {};
$(".activeInput").each(function() {
    map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});

alert(map.key1);
```

The issue I am having is I cannot seem to get the email value i.e the value of the data attribute email

In the console, if I do:

```
$('[email]')
```

It returns the whole span

If I try:

```
$('tr span').attr("email");
```

But I get: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function

And I have tried a few other variations without success so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure Gmail uses jQuery?

Comment: @palaѕн The Gmail site does not have a reference to jQuery. It uses `$()` for its own purposes. Your addition to the question is misplaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `$` in Gmail page is not a jQuery instance, instead, it refers to the Chrome [Console Utilities API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#queryselector)

As mentioned in the above docs:

> **$(selector, [startNode])**
>
> ---
>
> `$(selector)` returns the reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector. When called with one argument, this function is an alias for the `document.querySelector()` function.

Now, in your case:

```
$('tr span').attr("email");
```

We could have simply used `$$(selector)` which is equivalent to calling `document.querySelectorAll()` in chrome console, but it seems Gmail have disabled it. So, instead you can try:

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('tr [email]');
var emails = [...spans].map(x => x.getAttribute('email'))
console.log(emails)
```

This will return all the emails in an array variable `emails`